# FInd and strore index of array one using array two elements and store all index of array one in array 3

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have main array like this although it is not complete array but that;'s the format of array

```
newarr: Array(1)
0: Array(239)
[0 … 99]
0: i {transformMatrix: null, fill: "#FFFFFF", dirty: false, stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 0.172, …}
1: i {transformMatrix: null, fill: "#000000", dirty: false, stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 0.172, …}
2: i {transformMatrix: null, fill: "#FFFFFF", dirty: false, stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 0.172, …}
3: i {transformMatrix: null, fill: "#0000FF", dirty: false, stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 0.172, …}
4: i {transformMatrix: null, fill: "#FFFFFF", dirty: false, stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 0.172, …}
5: i {transformMatrix: null, fill: "#FFFFFF", dirty: false, stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 0.172, …}
```

The second array is where i am saving all unique colors from array one and it look like this

```
uniqueColors: Array(1)
0: "#FFFFFF"
1: "#000000"
2: "#0000FF"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Now i want to to use send array element to find search array one and save same color index in group form in third array.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to happen and can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: What code did you write to achieve this?

Comment: @Kobe what i want is if the color is black in arrray 2 at index[0] it will search all index in array one where color is black and save those index in array 3 like this 
array 3 (
 black:[0,4,8]
 blue : [2,3,9]
)

Comment: @void this code is what i am using to achieve this but it only saving 0 in array 3
 if (obj[i] == uniqueColors[j]){        
          // var id = canvas.getActiveObject()._objects[i].fill.indexOf(uniqueColors[j]);
          // if(id != -1){}
          var newvar = Array(newarr.fill[i]).indexOf(uniqueColors[j]);
          if(newvar != -1){
            patharray.push(newvar);
          }          
        }

Comment: Overall Program where i am trying to implement all this is in this js fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/Kakarot_123/Ls7dj2qt/17/

Answer (score 2):

This code does both steps:

```js
arr1 = [{
    transformMatrix: null,
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    dirty: false,
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 0.172
  },
  {
    transformMatrix: null,
    fill: "#000000",
    dirty: false,
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 0.172
  },
  {
    transformMatrix: null,
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    dirty: false,
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 0.172
  },
  {
    transformMatrix: null,
    fill: "#0000FF",
    dirty: false,
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 0.172
  },
  {
    transformMatrix: null,
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    dirty: false,
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 0.172
  },
  {
    transformMatrix: null,
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    dirty: false,
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 0.172
  }
]

dupe = new Set()
arr2 = arr1.filter(({fill}) => {
  if (dupe.has(fill)) {
    return false
  } else {
    dupe.add(fill)
    return true
  }
})

obj = arr2.reduce((acc1, {fill:f1}) => {
  acc1[f1] = arr1.reduce((acc2, {fill:f2}, i) => f1 === f2 ? [...acc2, i] : acc2, [])
  return acc1
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

1. Filter out all duplicates in `arr1` and return the rest to `arr2`, using a set to note the duplicates.
2. Reduce the array into an object, where each value is a reduced version of arr1, returning only the indices.

Comment: Hi, it work like charm but when i tried to push the obj in new array it did not work

Comment: @kakarot An object is a key value store, I wouldn't reccommend using an array here.

Comment: Not really. How will you know what the color is if it's in an array?

Comment: If we use 2d array can we not achieve  that ??

Comment: That's inefficient. I'm assuming you want to loop over the object? Use `Object.values()`.